# Testing for mutual exclusion in Erlang

Tags: erlang, mutex, mutual-exclusion

I currently have a simple bank account written using erlang, I also have the same bank account rewritten with a view to mutual exlusion the idea is so that two deposits cannot be made where the set/get balance can be interupted so that the end value is wrong for example bal A = 10 bal B = 20:

```
WRONG
get_bal.A 0 → get_bal.B 0 → set_bal.A 10 → set_bal.B 20 == 20
RIGHT
get_bal.A 0 → set_bal.A 10 → get_bal.B 10 → set_bal.B 30 == 30
```

My code initial code is as follows:

```
-module(bank).
-export([account/1, start/0, stop/0, deposit/1, get_bal/0, set_bal/1]).

account(Balance) ->
receive
    {set, NewBalance} ->
        account(NewBalance);
    {get, From} ->
        From ! {balance, Balance},
        account(Balance);
    stop -> ok
end.

start() ->
    Account_PID = spawn(bank, account, [0]),
    register(account_process, Account_PID).

stop() ->
    account_process ! stop,
    unregister(account_process).

set_bal(B) ->
    account_process ! {set, B}.

get_bal() ->
    account_process ! {get, self()},
    receive
    {balance, B} -> B
end.

deposit(Amount) ->
    OldBalance = get_bal(),
    NewBalance = OldBalance + Amount,
    set_bal(NewBalance).
```

The idea is to set up a test so that i can receive an error if the final balance can be wrong and a pass if it goes as planned.
My re-written code is also as follows:

```
account(Balance) ->
receive
    {deposit, Amount, From} ->
        NewBalance = Balance + Amount,
        From ! {deposit, Amount, NewBalance},
        account(NewBalance);
    {withdraw, Amount, From} when Amount > Balance ->
        From ! {error, {insufficient_funds, Amount, Balance}},
        account(Balance);
    {withdraw, Amount, From} ->
        NewBalance = Balance - Amount,
        From ! {withdrawal, Amount, NewBalance},
        account(NewBalance);    
    {get, From} ->
        From ! {balance, Balance},
        account(Balance);
    stop -> ok
end.

deposit(Amount) when Amount > 0 ->
account_process ! {deposit, Amount, self()},
receive
    {deposit, Amount, NewBalance} ->
        {ok, NewBalance}
end.

withdraw(Amount) when Amount > 0 ->
account_process ! {withdraw, Amount, self()},
receive
    {withdrawal, Amount, NewBalance} ->
        {ok, NewBalance};
    Error ->
        Error
end.
```

Thanks for reading and any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I updated my answer with a code sample. I re-implemented your bank functionality as an Erlang gen_server. This is a more "Erlangy" way of building the bank functionality.

Answer (score 1):

In Erlang mutual exclusion is not an issue. **Processes are actors and no memory is shared between them.**

Take a look at this question: [Is it easy to write traditional concurrency problems in Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024695/is-it-easy-to-write-traditional-concurrency-problems-in-erlang)

As for the code, I would probably do something like this (the "bank" is represented as a gen_server). This isn't really the solution to your issue, but a different way of achieving the same thing using OTP:

```
-module(bank).

-behaviour(gen_server).

%% API
-export([start_link/0, new_account/1, withdraw/2, deposit/2, get_bal/1]).

%% gen_server callbacks
-export([init/1,
     handle_call/3,
     handle_cast/2,
     handle_info/2,
     terminate/2,
     code_change/3]).

-record(state, {accounts = [] :: list()}).

%%%===================================================================
%%% API
%%%===================================================================

start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

new_account(Name) ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {new_account, Name}).

deposit(Account, Amount) when Amount > 0 ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {deposit, Account, Amount}).

withdraw(Account, Amount) when Amount > 0 ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {withdraw, Account, Amount}).

get_bal(Account) ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {get_bal, Account}).

%%%===================================================================
%%% gen_server callbacks
%%%===================================================================

init([]) ->
    {ok, #state{}}.

handle_call({new_account, Name}, _From, State) ->
    Accounts = State#state.accounts,
    case find_account(Name, Accounts) of
        none ->
            {reply, {account_created, Name}, State#state{accounts=[{Name, 0}|Accounts]}};
        _ ->
            {reply, already_exists, State}
        end;

handle_call({get_bal, Account}, _From, State) ->
    Accounts = State#state.accounts,
    {_Name, Balance} = find_account(Account, Accounts),
    {reply, Balance, State};

handle_call({deposit, Account, Amount}, _From, State) ->
    Accounts = State#state.accounts,
    {Name, Balance} = find_account(Account, Accounts),
    NewBalance = Balance + Amount,
    NewAccounts = lists:keyreplace(Name, 1, Accounts, {Name, NewBalance}),
    {reply, {deposit, Amount, NewBalance}, State#state{accounts=NewAccounts}};

handle_call({withdraw, Account, Amount}, _From, State) ->
    Accounts = State#state.accounts,
    {Name, Balance} = find_account(Account, Accounts),
     case Amount of
        Amount when Amount > Balance ->
            {reply, {insufficient_funds, Amount, Balance}, State};
        _ ->
            NewBalance = Balance - Amount,
            NewAccounts = lists:keyreplace(Name, 1, Accounts, {Name, NewBalance}),
            {reply, {withdrawal, Amount, NewBalance}, State#state{accounts=NewAccounts}}
    end;

handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    Reply = not_implemented,
    {reply, Reply, State}.

handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

%%%===================================================================
%%% Internal functions
%%%===================================================================
find_account(Account, Accounts) ->
    proplists:lookup(Account, Accounts).
```

Comment: You're exactly right, but this won't make sense to the OP until he actually writes enough Erlang programs for the true nature of the programming model to sink in.

Comment: That's the point I'm just trying to learn how to test for these things within Erlang

Comment: I will update my answer more information. While being correct, it's not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One way to test this is to have two or more bank client processes that interleave their messages to the bank. Each client process could be initialized with a list of messages to send to the bank, and each would then sit in a loop waiting for a message from some controller process to tell it to send its next message to the bank. The controller would act as a gate, telling each client in turn to send its next message, so that the overall effect would be that client messages would get mixed together.

If you had two such clients controlled like this, here's what would happen if they performed the sequence shown in your question using your original bank code if client A wanted to deposit 10 and client B wanted to deposit 20:

1. A does `get_bal`, gets 0
2. B does `get_bal`, gets 0
3. A does `set_bal(0+10)`, and the account now holds 10
4. B does `set_bal(0+20)`, and the account now holds 20

Clearly this is incorrect, as the resulting account balance should be 30.

Applying the same client sequence with the correct bank results in the correct amount:

1. A does `deposit(10)`, and the account now holds 10
2. B does `deposit(20)`, and the account now holds 30

Answer (score 1):

As @Stratus says, the way you wrote the second method guarantee that there is no risk of race condition in the deposit method since the account process itself makes the operations get balance + update balance in a single transaction.

If you want to convince yourself and compare the 2 methods you can spawn many processes that update the same account in parallel and compare the actual balance after all deposits are done to the expected one. The following code does the test for deposit:

```
-module(bank).
-export([account/1, start/0, stop/0, deposit1/1, deposit2/1, get_bal/0, set_bal/1, withdraw/1]).

%test

-export ([test/3,user/3]).

account(Balance) ->
receive
    {set, NewBalance} ->
        account(NewBalance);
    {get, From} ->
        From ! {balance, Balance},
        account(Balance);
    {deposit, Amount, From} ->
        NewBalance = Balance + Amount,
        From ! {deposit, Amount, NewBalance},
        account(NewBalance);
    {withdraw, Amount, From} when Amount > Balance ->
        From ! {error, {insufficient_funds, Amount, Balance}},
        account(Balance);
    {withdraw, Amount, From} ->
        NewBalance = Balance - Amount,
        From ! {withdrawal, Amount, NewBalance},
        account(NewBalance);    
    stop -> ok
end.





start() ->
    Account_PID = spawn(bank, account, [0]),
    register(account_process, Account_PID).

stop() ->
    account_process ! stop,
    unregister(account_process).

set_bal(B) ->
    account_process ! {set, B}.

get_bal() ->
    account_process ! {get, self()},
    receive
        {balance, B} -> B
    end.

deposit1(Amount) ->
    OldBalance = get_bal(),
    NewBalance = OldBalance + Amount,
    set_bal(NewBalance).

deposit2(Amount) when Amount > 0 ->
    account_process ! {deposit, Amount, self()},
    receive
        {deposit, Amount, NewBalance} ->
            {ok, NewBalance}
    end.

withdraw(Amount) when Amount > 0 ->
    account_process ! {withdraw, Amount, self()},
    receive
        {withdrawal, Amount, NewBalance} ->
            {ok, NewBalance};
        Error ->
            Error
    end.


test(Nbuser, Nbdeposit, Method) ->
    start(),
    done = spawn_users(Nbuser,Nbdeposit,Method,self()),
    receive_loop(Nbuser),
    Res = (get_bal() == Nbdeposit*Nbuser),
    stop(),
    Res.

spawn_users(0,_Nbdeposit,_Method,_Pid) -> done;
spawn_users(Nbuser,Nbdeposit,Method,Pid) ->
    spawn(?MODULE,user,[Nbdeposit,Method,Pid]),
    spawn_users(Nbuser-1,Nbdeposit,Method,Pid).

receive_loop(0) -> done;
receive_loop(N) ->
    receive
        end_deposit -> receive_loop(N-1)
    end.

user(0,_,Pid) ->
    get_bal(), % to be sure that with method deposit1, the last set_bal is processed
    Pid ! end_deposit;
user(N,Method,Pid) ->
    ?MODULE:Method(1),
    user(N-1,Method,Pid).
```

And you can verify that with 2 users making 1 deposit you get an error with method 1, while with method 2 you have not even with 1000 users making 1000 deposits.

```
2> bank:test(1,100,deposit1).
true
3> bank:test(2,1,deposit1).  
false
4> bank:test(1,100,deposit2).
true
5> bank:test(2,1,deposit2).  
true
6> bank:test(1000,1000,deposit2).
true
```

**Remark**

The results will depend on the machine you are working on. I a using a quad core with smp, so the wrong method fails immediately, I guess that it may needs more users or deposit on a single core.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is similar to how one "improves bottleneck performance in Erlang". In the case of bottlenecks the goal is not to improve it (make it more performant), but rather to eliminate it entirely (which is only very rarely not possible).

In the case of exclusion, the goal is not to prove that you've "got a lock on data X for the duration of procedure Y and rollback to Z" but rather to write programs in a way where locks are completely unnecessary. I'm sure there are cases where this may not be avoidable, but I have never, ever encountered one in Erlang (at least not that I can remember). Processes don't share memory. This is why Steve Vinoski's answer to your previous (nearly identical) question ([Applying a mutex into an erlang example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554114/applying-a-mutex-into-an-erlang-example)) demonstrated how you should combine operations instead of parceling out steps of them in your external process API.

If you expose a procedure `add(Account, Value)` that just does exactly `loop(Current + Value)` without anything else happening, sure you're asking for trouble. But that's exposing an extremely low-level API, isn't it? The proper way to solve this is to do what Vinoski recommended and expose only a higher level API that combines the operations of value changes *and* reporting back the effect of the change. There is *no chance* that another pending operation of the same form coming from another process can change the value while you try to read it now, causing one or the other API call to get tripped up, because the API calls are *messages* which are queued, not C-style function calls occurring among different threads that may change the underlying value of the same location in memory in any arbitrary order without a lock on them.

The process mailbox *is* your mutex. If you use Erlang processes the way they are intended this class of bug simply does not exist. You can't screw it up. Every action is fully atomic, queued in order of message receipt, fully blocking/locking on the data, and the underlying data is *not accessible from outside in any case*.

*Each process already has an exclusive lock on all its data for the duration of its existence*.